# How to download multiple file objects of particular directory from AWS s3 using ASP.Net Core?

Tags: amazon-s3, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

How to download multiple file objects of particular directory (eg. folder name batch No. having multiple folders, inside subfolders having files like images or pdf files ) from AWS s3 using ASP.Net Core.

Comment: please check the documentation on how to use the S3 API filter with PREFIX,

Comment: @mootmoot i did tried few s3 api call like await transferUtility.DownloadDirectoryAsync , and ListObjectsResponse response = await client.ListObjectsAsync(request);, and await objresponse.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync , but only able to return   stream or List<stream> response

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3ListObjectsV2Request.html 
or 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3S3ListObjectsV2AsyncListObjectsV2RequestCancellationToken.html

Answer (score 0):

In this regard i would recommend creating a zipped file with all the directory contents and download it as one file